# Nomodeset issue and dual-boot with Win8/14.04 in Zenbook?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, secure-boot

I have a Zenbook UX302LA with Win8 pre-installed that I bought new in the summer of 2014. I now want to dual-boot it with Linux Ubuntu 14.04. I can get it to boot no problem off of the live USB with the following steps:

- Disabled SecureBoot in BIOS
- Disabled FastBoot
- Boot flag `nomodeset`

I am about to install Ubuntu on a 22GB partition I have created on the 500GB HDD. However before I install this I have a few questions:

1. Will there be a way to fix the `nomodeset` issue or at least some opportunity to type it in before every boot?
2. Also if I install it like this, will I have a successfully dual booted machine as in the bootloaders will not be messed up and I'll be able to pick which ever partition I want to boot to?

Ubuntu: 14.04
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX302LA
Dual-boot: Windows 8

Comment: The latest version of Ubuntu is in fact 14.10, and not 14.04. The difference being though that 14.04 is a Long Term Support version which comes with five years of security and maintenance updates, guaranteed. However 14.10 is not an LTS version, giving you only nine months of security and maintenance updates.

Comment: I see, I was incorrect however do you know if this will affect my installation? I have a new partition and will be installing the bot loader on the /dev/sda5 partition so should I be able to get a clean dual booted machine?

Comment: It is always recommended for security reasons to get the latest version of Ubuntu, and not wait for 6 months for an upgrade (LTS versions are released every 6 months). Although using your make an model with this search you should be able to find out which Ubuntu version suits your hardware requirements the best, as certain drivers for sound, wifi and Ethernet, etc, may not work if you get the 'wrong' version. Although all you will need to do then is to install the correct drivers if any of them stop working due to you getting the 'wrong' version.

Comment: Here is the search: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/models/?query=&release=&level=Any&vendors=Asus

Comment: @DomFarolino Have you found answers to your questions? Please, consider to accept the answer or answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Always take a full system back-up before starting. Read [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) why.**

1. Yes
2. Depending on the set-up of your machine's BIOS/UEFI and the setup of Windows 8: maybe